# Unknown provider injecting factory

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

When I run my app it always throws the following error:

> `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: localStorageServiceProvider <- localStorageService
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/unpr?p0=localStorageServiceProvider%20%3C-%20localStorageService`

This is my Code: 
home.js:

```
   angular.module('home', [])

.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'localStorageService',
    function ($scope, $location, localStorageService) {
        $scope.username = "maax",
        $scope.buttonType = "icon ion-search",
        $scope.buttonDisable = false,

        $scope.click = function () {
            $scope.buttonDisable = true
            $scope.buttonType = "icon ion-loading-a"

            //Grap geoLocation        
            var location = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sendToServer);

            function sendToServer(pos) {
                //sendGeoData(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude, window.localStorage.getItem("userId"))
                savePlayerData("sd");
            }

            //Ask server for availalble player an get data

            //End server request


            //Link to play-screen
            $location.path("/tab/play-screen");
            localStorageService.addEvent();
        };

}])
```

Here is my service, that I try to inject:

```
'use strict'
angular.module('service', [])

//var testEvent = {
//    "playerName": "Max",
//    "aufgabe": "Döner kaufen"
//}
//
//localStorage.setItem('events', testEvent);
//Create a hitsotry of Events to see the recent Events

.factory('localStorageService', function () {
    return {
        addEvent: function () {
            return null
        }
    }
    //
    //    return 1;
    //    //Pull the current events
    //    var event = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('events'));
    //
    //    /*overwrite the localStorage with the newest Event added in 
    //            the begining */
    //
    //    var eventUpdatet = newEvent;
    //    eventUpdatet.push(events);
    //    localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(eventUpdated));

});
```

I hope you can help me, because I really do not see my error.
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to plug the dependency of both modules, fix this line:

```
angular.module('home', ['service'])
```

Comment: unfortunateley does not help!
now it says: "angular.js:63 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module home due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module services due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'services' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

Comment: make sure you add both files in your index.html, where servicemodule.js is loaded above @user3122136